# How can I send this curl as tcl/http instead?

Tags: api, curl, tcl, spotify

I'm trying to trigger "play" -funtion with spotify API and tcl/http.

Here is the concept, in curl: https://developer.spotify.com/console/put-play/

```sh
curl -X "PUT" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play" --data "{\"context_uri\":\"spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr\",\"offset\":{\"position\":5},\"position_ms\":0}" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "
```

Here's a working example with tcl using exec curl:

```
set url https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=$device_id
set data "{\"context_uri\":\"spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr\",\"offset\":{\"position\":5},\"position_ms\":0}"
if {[catch {
    exec curl -X "PUT" "$url" --data $data -H "Accept: application/json" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $oauth"
} msg]} then {
    puts $msg
}
```

But i'd like to do it with tcl/http, if it's possible.

Here is my best shot so far doing this with http, but it says "malformed json".

```
if {$incoming == ".play"} {
    ::http::register https 443 {::tls::socket -autoservername 1}
    ::http::config -urlencoding utf-8 -useragent {JSON curl/7.55. 1}

    set spot_url [http::geturl https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play? \
        -method PUT \
        -query {{device_id:"d70b1f06*MASKED*36c308", 
            "context_uri":"spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr","offset":{"position":5},"position_ms":0}} \
        -headers [list Accept application/json Content-Type application/json Authorization "Bearer $::access_token"]]

    set spot_temp [::http::data $spot_url]
    ::http::cleanup $spot_temp
    ::http::cleanup $spot_url

    return $spot_temp
}
```

Any idea how to send it correct to avoid malformed json? :D
Thanks!

Comment: The `device_id` key is unquoted.

Comment: Thank you! It works!

Comment: It might be worth composing the query data with rl_json.

Comment: Is it necessary to set the urlencoding and useragent properties? The former, surely not (the URL is basic ASCII) but the latter?